Visualforce/Flow styling from List View button
I have a requirement to perform updates to a custom object (UserDefinedConfig__c) from a List View button. UserDefinedConfig__c stores custom config for two different objects (Task, Action Plan). UserDefinedConfig__c for Task requires one target User and config for Action Plan requires 2 target Users plus a target Action Plan Template.
So the idea is that a User will choose UserDefinedConfig__c records from List View, press a List View button. User will then be presented a screen for updating all the UserDefinedConfig__c records for Task config, press a next button to be taken to another screen for updating all the config records for Action Plan and then press save.
This has led me down the paths of looking into Flows from List View and Visualforce with Aura app with LWC embedded to pass the selected ids from the List View into a custom piece.
Functionally, both methods work. Visually, neither work because styling inside of the custom pieces is not picking up custom styles from Themes and Branding.
This is where I need advice. I want to apply the same style we have setup in Themes and Branding to one of the custom pieces but I'm not figuring out or finding a good way to do this.
